# Wix Install the same Version

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a wix installer with five features. My current version is 0.0.0.125. I am installing this in one machine with first three features. Later i wish to install the remaining two features and so deselected first three and selected the remaining two features. 
So this time the first three already installed should not be deleted, and the remaining two features should be installed. But when i install the same build second time, the three features are automatically removed from the destination location and the selected two features only installed.

I used RemoveFile child attribute to each Component to overwrite and when i manually copied the file and pasted into the destination directory, next time when i install the same version installer, it is not overwriting and deselected(previously installed features) features also deleted. So i have restricted this by adding 1 in InstallExecuteSequence.

i)I need to overwrite all the files
ii) Each installation of the same installer should not delete the previously installed files

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell exactly what you mean by features and installing the same setup twice, but:

You cannot install the same MSI setup twice. It's already installed (the ProductCode) so it will go into maintenance/repair mode. This may do a repair/reinstall or, if you've authored it for feature maintenance, then Windows will again notice that the product is already installed but offer the standard feature dialog which lets you add features from the setup, and this latter mode is exactly what you get if you go to Programs&Features and choose change. In other words a true feature maintenance setup offers the feature selection dialog primarily from Programs&Features, and in your scenario with adding two features you'd simply use Change from Programs&Features and not attempt to reinstall the same setup.

Your post refers to Components and RemoveFile, and you should definitely not need to do any of this. If you're not using true Windows Installer features and have built a Component-based setup where Component installation is based on conditions then that would explain what you are seeing. The property values used for your conditions are not preserved so when you attempt to install the same setup again it goes into maintenance reinstall mode for the currently installed product, the property values are empty, the conditions are false, so those components are removed.

Having said all that, you haven't posted your WiX, and the fact that you're attempting to install the same setup twice implies you may not be familiar with maintenance, features and components. In summary, it seems that you should be using the WixUI_FeatureTree dialog set, grouping your components into features to achieve what you're looking for.

If your aim is to replace files that need updating then you should look at the WiX MajorUpgrade element. If you set MigrateFeatures to yes then the upgrade will result in the same features still be installed after the upgrade. Schedule afterInstallExecute is probably what you want. Increment file versions of files you want updating, use a new ProductCode, increment the ProductVersion in the first three fields and use the same UpgradeCode. Alternatively you could look at creating a patch, an msp file.

Comment: I don't want to go maintenance mode once i install the product. Instead always it should install as the first time installation. As you said am using "SelectionTree" control to grouping the components. 
 <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Whole Prodcut" Level="1"><Feature Id="FirstFeature" Title="First Feature" Level="1">         <ComponentGroupRef Id="FirstFeatureComponents/>
</Feature><Feature Id="SecondFeature" Title="Second Feature" Level="1"><ComponentGroupRef Id="SecondFeatureComponents/>"
      </Feature></Feature>

Comment: Cannot be done - you are unaware of the way Windows Installer works. The product defined by the ProductCode has been installed, and running the same ProductCode setup again will not install as if it's the first time install. Perhaps you should look at MajorUpgrade element and migrating feature states.

Comment: You are correct PhilDW. We want to achieve this. I use * in the ProdcutCode. I am planning to delete the ProductCode from the registry during AppSearch if installed already by searching the ProductName. So it will always like the first installation. I removed manintenance dialog and added the CDATA (NOT Installed OR Installed OR PATCH) to show all my dialog boxes. So in first/second/third installation of the same build version shows the same dialog boxes and also executing the all defined custom actions.

Comment: My ultimate aim is to overwrite the previously installed files. When i manually copied and paste a file into the destination folder and running the installer of a new build is not overwriting the file even the installer has newer file. When i delete the file from the destination folder and running the installer again, it installs the files. How do i achieve this overwriting.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would set `Permanent="yes"` for files that you want to keep on a computer after un-installation and "no" if want to remove or overwrite them.

For example:

```
      <util:XmlFile Id="fileId"
                Action="setValue"
                Permanent="yes"
                File='[INSTALLFOLDER]pathtofile\yourApp.exe'
                ElementPath="" 
                Value=""
                Sequence="1"/>
```

Hope this helps!